# React Js: How to render a using a template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

I did the following using jquery. I want to achieve the same thing using react js but i don't how to render it more than once.

jsFiddle- https://jsfiddle.net/uxzdfsLj/4/

React js code

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import $ from 'jquery';

var Note = React.createClass({
componentDidMount : function(){

       ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.nameInput).focus()

},

create:function(event){

    if(event.charCode == 13) {
    alert('Enter... (KeyPress, use charCode)');

}},


render :function(){
    return( 
    <div class="reply">
    <input type="text" class="text"  ref="nameInput" placeholder="Enter Text Here..." onKeyPress={this.create}></input>
    </div>
    )
}

});




ReactDOM.render(<Note/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Describe what you want to achieve

Comment: just like the jsFiddle i want to render multiple smaller sections on keypress

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html) to render user-enterd HTML:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: '<h1>Go</h1>'}} />
```

Note, however, that you should use it with extreme care. User-inputed HTML can open your app up for security vulnerabilities, if what is entered is stored on the server somewhere and sent to other users.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your html in render method and just change your

```
componentDidMount : function(){

       ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.nameInput).focus()

},
```

to

```
componentDidMount : function(){

       this.refs.nameInput.focus()

},
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but i was looking for on how to render multiple smaller components